# Populate an array with multiple mongo queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

I'm having a problem with a callback mess.

In my nodejs app, I'm trying to get an array of JSON Objects returned by a mongoDB request. I don't know why, but it don't populate as I want.

I suspect a problem of asynchronous results/callback mess.

```
var fruits = ["Peach", "Banana", "Strawberry"];
var finalTab = [];
fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
    db.collection('mycollection').distinct("column1", {"column2":{$regex :fruit}}, (function(err, result) {                 
        finalTab[fruit] = result;
        console.log(result); // -> display the desired content
        db.close();
        if (err) throw err;
    }));
});
console.log(finalTab); // -> []
```

Thanks by advance for help.

EDIT : 
As I need all results returned by my db.collection...functions... I'm trying to add these async commands to a queue, execute it and get a callback function.
I think that async nodejs module can help.

Can someone tell me how to do this in a ForEach() ?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Finally got the right way to do it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902134/5119290

Answer (score 0):

The line `finalTab[fruit] = result;` will not help because `fruit` there is not index. You need to use index in `forEach()` as follows -

```
var fruits = ["Peach", "Banana", "Strawberry"];
var finalTab = [];
fruits.forEach(function(fruit, index) {
    db.collection('mycollection').distinct("column1", {"column2":{$regex :fruit}}, (function(err, result) {                 
        finalTab[index] = result;
        console.log(result); // -> display the desired content
        db.close();
        if (err) throw err;
    }));
});
console.log(finalTab); // -> []
```

Comment: While this is a baby step in the right direction, there are still multiple problems with your code.

Comment: Is it possible to use the content of the fruit variable as a key of the array ?
Like this ->
[
    'Peach' => {myobject},
    'Banana' => ....etc
]

Comment: I edited my question Patrick. Can you help ?

Comment: Response here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902134/5119290